# Condicional AND no funciona para consultas sobre la misma columna?

Tags: sql

El siguiente código con un solo condicional funciona

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID <10;
```

Pero no así si escribo algo como

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID <10 AND CustomerID>20;
```

Por qué? Cómo consulto ID menores que 10 pero mayores 20 por ejemplo?

Y disculpas pero recién estoy comenzando.

Comment: y no.. el campo CustomerID no puede valer en la misma fila menos que 10 y mas que 20.. deberias usar un or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cómo consulto ID menores que 10 pero mayores 20 por ejemplo?

Lo que planteas en la pregunta es imposible. No existen ID (o números) menores que 10 y a la vez mayores que 20.

OPCIONES:

**1 -** Seleccionar los números que sean menores que 10 y también los que sean mayores que 20:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID < 10 OR CustomerID > 20;
```

Devolvería **todos los números menos** 10, 11, ... , 19, 20.

**2 -** Seleccionar todos los números que no estén entre 10 y 20 (incluidos):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Devolvería también **todos los números menos** 10, 11, ... , 19, 20.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID <10 OR CustomerID>20;
```

Comment: Falta que expliques más tu respuesta. No es bueno poner sólo el código.

Answer (score 0):

es SQL Server? en ese caso puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
Select * from Customers where CustomerId between 10 and 20
```

Por otro lado tu sql está mal formado tiene que ser CustomerId>10 and CustomerId<20 dado que si buscas menor a 10 solo quedan (9,8,7....0) y al mismo tiempo mayor que 20 solo quedan (21....100) es decir no hay forma de que te devuelva los datos que buscas.

Ahora si bien si quieres todos menos los que estan entre 10 y 20 osea 11,12,13...19 tendria que ser **customerId<10 or customerId>20** es decir traeme todos los que son menores a 10 o que son mayores a 20 de esa forma te quitaria esos numeros intermedios.